# SOQL nested query not working

Tags: apex, soql, query, list, nested

I want to save the following query but it given me errors:

Query:

```
Set<Id> extUserIdSet = new Set<Id>();

List<Object1> obj1= [
    SELECT Id, ExternalId, Name, Address,
      ( SELECT User_Country__c 
        FROM User 
        WHERE User_Country__c == 'United Kingdom')
    FROM Object1
    WHERE ExternalId IN :extUserIdSet
];
```

When I try to save the file, it gives me the following error:

[image]

Comment: Hi Manto, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Please do not change your question to pivot to a different issue after you receive an answer which resolves what you were facing. Instead, accept that answer and ask a new question if you are still stuck. Also, a bit of basic research is recommended, the relationship name is a common issue that has been asked often on this site and has a Canonical Q&A.

Comment: Post the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use a single "=" , not double "==" . Please refer to the [SOQL documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_alias.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed it to single '=' but now it gives me a new error. I updated the question. please help

Comment: that it not the same as your original error. As suggested, please review the SOQL documentation to better understand how to query data. also, please don't ask follow up questions in your posts. keep things to 1 Post per question. Thanks